# What should be used for additional information? Comma or Semi-colon?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

Which of the following is correct?

> My family is part of the Miami tribe; a Native American people with strong ties to territory in present-day Ohio, Indiana and Illinois.

OR

> My family is part of the Miami tribe, a Native American people with strong ties to territory in present-day Ohio, Indiana and Illinois.

Comment: Second one, since a Native American people...is used as appositive.

Comment: Long or "em" dash would also work, but not semicolon or colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Semicolons** are used to link two sentences into one, as in

> You are here; I am not.

or to separate items in a list after a colon or when the items have commas within them (which would make use of a comma as a separator confusing):

> I need a bowl, of any color and size you have; and measuring spoons.

[The Writing Center](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html) has more.

So **a semicolon wouldn't work here**.

**A comma is fine**:  in fact, this is a primary use of commas.  [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-oxford-appositive-nonrestrictive?page=1)   shows several examples of using a comma in this way.

**A colon is also OK**.  It can be used to separate an explanation of what comes previously.  See rule 4 of this page from [Grammar Book](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp).

Answer (score 0):

**Neither.**

The correct punctuation mark to use here is **the colon**: because it is [a punctuation mark used "before a list or an explanation that is preceded by a clause that can stand by itself."](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/colon.htm)

See what I did there?

> "My family is part of the Miami tribe"

stands perfectly well by itself, and the remainder of the sentence is explanation.